# Why can't I define <T where T : CharSequence, T : Appendable> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Code A define a generic `fun ensureTrailingPeriod` with parameter restrain.

1: I think Code A is hard to understand, and maybe Code B is good, right?

2: And more, I think that `ensureTrailingPeriod` return `Unit` with Code A, but Code C is wrong, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
fun <T> ensureTrailingPeriod(seq: T)
    where T : CharSequence, T : Appendable{
    if (!seq.endsWith('.')) {
        seq.append('.')
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun <T where T : CharSequence, T : Appendable> ensureTrailingPeriod1(seq: T)  {
    if (!seq.endsWith('.')) {
        seq.append('.')
    }
}
```

**Code C**

```
fun <T> ensureTrailingPeriod(seq: T)
     where T : CharSequence, T : Appendable  :Unit{
       if (!seq.endsWith('.')) {
         seq.append('.')
     }
}
```

Comment: I think option `C` works if you put `: Unit` before the `where` clause. The syntax in option `B` is simply not valid Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That's literally just what the syntax of the language is, multiple constraints have to be defined with `where`, and they have to be at the end of the function header, and not where single constraints go.
2. Any explicit return types are also before the `where` constraints:

   ```
   fun <T> ensureTrailingPeriod(seq: T): Unit where T : CharSequence, T : Appendable {
       if (!seq.endsWith('.')) {
           seq.append('.')
       }
   }
   ```

For reference, you can find this in the [Kotlin grammar](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#function) as well:

```
function (used by memberDeclaration, declaration, topLevelObject)
  : modifiers "fun"
      typeParameters?
      (type ".")?
      SimpleName
      typeParameters? valueParameters (":" type)?
      typeConstraints
      functionBody?
  ;
```

This clearly tells you what order the different parts of a function declaration come in. First, there are modifiers (visibility, infix, etc), then the `fun` keyword, then type parameters, the receiver type in case the function is an extension, the name, the parameter list, the optional return type, and finally the type constraints before the body of the function.